# How to transfer file from Windows to Linux server, process it with shell script, and download results back

Tags: linux, windows, shell, sftp, scp

I normally do this using WinSCP: I transfer a `.tex` file from my local Windows machine to a Linux server. I run a script (on the server) to `pdflatex` the file for me. And I use WinSCP again to copy the output `.pdf` to my local Windows machine again. I would like to automate the copying process in my script.

So the first step is to copy `file.tex` from `C:\Doc...\source` to `~/Documents`. I think I need to use the `scp` command, but the server sees my local machine as a remote machine. That's why I'm confused as to how the first directory needs to be specified:

```
$scp C:\Doc...\source\file.tex ~/Documents
```

doesn't work because the server doesn't know how to talk to my local machine. I have the same issue for the `scp` command I need to use to copy `file.pdf` back to my local Windows machine.

Can anybody help me with these two scp commands?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [WinSCP in scripting mode](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation). It (naturally) supports the upload/download. But it can also execute the shell script on the server with [`call` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_call) (with some limitations, which should not matter in your simple case):

```
winscp.com /log=winscp.log /command ^
    "open scp://username:password@example.com/" ^
    "cd /remote/path" ^
    "put my.tex" ^
    "call pdflatex ..." ^
    "get my.pdf" ^
    "exit"
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*